# Set a value for prompt in select Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `select` dropdown in a form but was looking to set the prompt value as "0"

```
<%= f.select :image_size_id, options_for_select(@image_sizes.collect{ |i| [i.dimension] }), { prompt: "Please select a Print Size" }, id: 'image_size_select' %>
```

This generates

```
<select id="image_size_select" name="cart_item[image_size_id]">
  <option value="">Please select a Print Size</option>
  <option value="1">10x8</option>
  <option value="2">A4</option>
  <option value="3">A3</option>
  <option value="4">A2</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery I can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#image_size_select option[value=""]').val('0')
});
```

But I was looking to do this using the select helper. Can it be set this way?

Comment: Why do you want to set the prompt value as 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add it to the array of values used by options_for_select instead of using the "prompt" option, which always sets a blank value.  You should also make the array of sizes have two elements in each subarray: one for the displayed text and one for the value.

```
<% options = [["Please select a Print Size",0]] + @image_sizes.collect{ |i| [i.dimension, i.dimension] } %>
<%= f.select :image_size_id, options_for_select(options), id: 'image_size_select' %>
```

Comment: Almost posted the same answer :) It is not a "prompt" if it has a value. And also it worth to mention that those calculations should happen somewhere in decorator on in the helper, but not inside a view.

Comment: Agreed on that.  I always have them as a model class method but i think this might not be the most "correct" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
<%= f.select :image_size_id, options_for_select([["Please select a Print Size", 0]] + @image_sizes.pluck(:dimension, :id)), {}, id: 'image_size_select' %>
```